# Calling function including pointer parameters

Tags: c, struct

Let's say I have a sunglasses shop.
My structures (bottom to top):

```
typedef struct Model
{
    int m_Num;
    int m_amount;
}model;
typedef struct Brand
{
    char b_name[20];
    int b_amount;
    int b_NumOfModels;
    model ** models;
}brand;
typedef struct Store
{
    char * s_Name;
    int s_NumOfBrands;
    int s_TotalSg;
    brand ** brands;
}store;
```

I have built "createStore/Brand/Model" functions - checked, worked perfectly.
The next part I want to pay attention to is after I have created a store, I want to be able to add more stores/brands/models.
I have tried for example adding some random brand:

```
store * insertBrand(store*, char*);
```

and as feedback, I want to get a message if the brand exists or does not exist:

```
int main()
{
    store* moshSstore = createStore();
    store* insertBrand();
    return 0;
}

store * insertBrand(store *s, char* brandName)
{
    int i, j, found;
    for (i = 0; i < s->s_NumOfBrands; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(s->brands[i]->b_name, brandName) == 0)
            break;
    }
    if (i < s->s_NumOfBrands)   //found
        printf("brand has been found");

    else                        //not found
        printf("brand not found");
}
```

This is my code. I have tried to debug but I don't understand why the `insertBrand` function is not working (not working at all).

Comment: You didn't show us `createStore()`.  Do you actually initialize the values within the allocated structure?  If you don't that is the most likely cause of your troubles.  That, plus the fact that you call `insertBrand()` with no arguments from main even though your definition shows two arguments.  Makes me think that this won't even compile, let alone work.

Comment: There are no calls to `insertBrand` in the code you posted.  You have a useless declaration of it in `main`, which you should remove.  But where is it actually called?

Comment: you called insertBrand with no arguments.

Comment: @morels: nope - declared, not called.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: the function is declared, not called, in `main()`.

Comment: Oh, look at that.  What an odd thing to do.  Thanks.  I have to add that to my list of "Stupid C tricks" in the class that I teach. ;)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that is not better...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must check your creation function. You also you have put this line in the main without any parameters `store* insertBrand();` you didn't return any value into your `insertBrand` — however you had a return type in your definition function `store*`.  You must ensure of initializing the structure when you create it and ensure of the brands initializing also.

In your main function you put a declaration of the function:

```
store* insertBrand();
```

This is not a call to `insertBrand`; it's just a (non-prototype) function declaration.

Comment: That line (re)declares the function without giving it a prototype.  It is not a function call.  It is neither a good idea nor what is really wanted, but it is 'legitimate' C.

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry for the mess, didnt want to make a too big question with a lot of code in it.
however, for those who ask:

```
store * createStore()
{
    char name[SIZE];
    int i, j;
    store* newStore = (store*)malloc(sizeof(store));
    if (newStore == NULL)
    {
        puts("allocating error");
        free(newStore);
        return NULL;
    }
    puts("enter store name : (32 ch. MAX");
    getchar(name);
    gets(name);
    newStore->s_Name = strdup(name);
    if (newStore->s_Name == NULL)
    {
        puts("allocating error");
        free(newStore->s_Name);
        free(newStore);
    }
    puts("enter total number of sunglasses : ");
    scanf("%d", &(newStore->s_TotalSg));

    puts("enter number of brands : ");
    scanf("%d", &(newStore->s_NumOfBrands));

    newStore->brands = (brand**)calloc(sizeof(newStore->s_NumOfBrands), sizeof(brand*));
    if (newStore->brands == NULL)
    {
        puts("allocating error");
        free(newStore->s_Name);
        free(newStore->s_NumOfBrands);
        free(newStore->s_TotalSg);
        free(newStore->brands);
        free(newStore);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < newStore->s_NumOfBrands; i++)
    {
        newStore->brands[i] = createBrand();
        if (newStore->brands[i] == NULL)
        {
            puts("allocating error");
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(newStore->brands[j]);
            free(newStore->s_Name);
            free(newStore->s_NumOfBrands);
            free(newStore->s_TotalSg);
            free(newStore->brands);
            free(newStore);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return newStore;
}
```

is it helpfull for my question?

Answer (score 0):

Hi your function contains some mistakes, so i will just list them here :
1. Why you try to apply free function on a pointer you tested before and is NULL and integer

```
free(newStore); // line 9 of the function
free(newStore->s_Name); // line 19
free(newStore->s_NumOfBrands); // line 33 and 48
free(newStore->s_TotalSg); // line 34 and 49
```

2. This line isn't correct i think

   newStore->brands = (brand**)calloc(sizeof(newStore->s_NumOfBrands), sizeof(brand*));

You want to do this i think :

```
newStore->brands = (brand**)calloc(newStore->s_NumOfBrands, sizeof(brand*));
```

This is a quick clean up of your code check it and improve it also check you createBrand

```
store * createStore()
{
    char name[SIZE];
    int i, j;
    store* newStore = (store*)malloc(sizeof(store));
    if (newStore == NULL) {
        puts("allocating error");
        return NULL;
    }
    puts("enter store name : (32 ch. MAX");
    getchar(name); // you can use scanf instead of this two lines
    gets(name);
    newStore->s_Name = strdup(name);
    if (newStore->s_Name == NULL) {
        puts("allocating error");
        free(newStore);
        return NULL;
    }
    puts("enter total number of sunglasses : ");
    scanf("%d", &(newStore->s_TotalSg));

    puts("enter number of brands : ");
    scanf("%d", &(newStore->s_NumOfBrands));

    newStore->brands = (brand**)calloc(newStore->s_NumOfBrands, sizeof(brand*));
    if (newStore->brands == NULL) {
        puts("allocating error");
        free(newStore->s_Name);
        free(newStore);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < newStore->s_NumOfBrands; i++) {
        newStore->brands[i] = createBrand();
        if (newStore->brands[i] == NULL) {
            puts("allocating error");
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(newStore->brands[j]);
            free(newStore->s_Name);
            free(newStore->brands);
            free(newStore);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return newStore;
}
```